# How to select radio with similar unique_id

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I need to select radio buttons with similar unique_id when I select one of the existing radio buttons. 
Here is the code:

```
$('.test li input:radio').change(function () {

    var unique_id = $(this).attr('unique_id');
    $('input:radio').each(function () {

        if ($(this).attr('unique_id') == unique_id) {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        }

    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3R52F/4/)

In google chrome it is working but not always. It may work and may not work. Try to select radios many times. In Mozilla it doesn't work at all. 
What am I to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.test li input:radio').change(function(){
    $('input[unique_id="'+$(this).attr('unique_id')+'"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3R52F/1/)

Browsers automatically un-check radio inputs when another radio with the same `name` property is checked, so as long as all your radio groups have the same `unique_id` items you don't have to do that manually. Also the `change` event only fires for a radio input when it is checked, hence you just have to check all radios with the same `unique_id` attribute when one changes to keep the groups synced.

---

As for *why* your original code wasn't working in Firefox, you should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the `checked` property. [Avoid using `.attr()` to set DOM element properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/1331430). See your original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3R52F/2/) now using `.prop()`. I can't find any logic mistake besides that, though it can be further simplified setting the `checked` property with vanilla JS:

```
$('.test li input:radio').change(function(){
    var unique_id = $(this).attr('unique_id');
    $('input:radio').each(function(){
        this.checked = $(this).attr('unique_id') == unique_id;
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3R52F/3/)

---

This question has received an answer on [CodersClan](http://www.codersclan.net/forum/ticket.php?ticket_id=50).

Answer (score 0):

$('.test li input[type="radio"]').change(function(evt){

```
var other_el= $('.test li input[type="radio"][unique_id="' + $(evt.target).attr('unique_id') + '"]').not($(evt.target));


if (other_el.length === 1){
    other_el.attr('checked', $(evt.target).has(':checked')); 
}
```

});

here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4Ah/1/

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but here is the same problem as in my code. Try to select radio-buttons many times. In Mozilla sometimes it is working and sometimes is not.